# Output as HTML instead of plain text

Tags: java, html, eclipse

Instead of the old System.out.println(); for debugging; would it be possible to output as html and have the (text)results of my execution a little more expressive.

That way I would be able to do things like

```
System.out.println("<b>...</b> ...");
```

or perhaps more interestingly write out tables 'n stuff. Colors would also be an interesting dimension to have in debugging/producing output.

How could one do this (effectively) in eclipse?

Thanks :)

Comment: That's not true. I'll fix it asap. Thanks for pointing out. Wasn't aware that answers had to be accepted. Reading that article now...

Comment: `@kornfridge`: Good deal. Yeah, it's one of the differences between Stack Overflow and the million "forum" / "discussion" sites out there. :-)

Answer (score 3):

What you should do is use your own Logger class, such as this:

```
public class HtmlLogger {

  private static File file = new File("outputfile.html");
  private static DataOutputStream out;

     private static void start() {
         try {
          out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file, true));
       } catch (IOException ex) {...}
     }

     // Returns size in Kb
     private static long fileSize() {
         return file.length() / 1024;
     }

     // You can call this method whatever you like.
     public static void html(String line) {
         if (out == null) start();
         synchronized (out) {
             try {
               out.writeBytes(line + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
               out.flush();
           } catch (IOException ex) {...}
        }
     }
}
```

So what you can do is import a static HtmlLogger, `import static HtmlLogger.*;` and output HTML per line like this: `html("<p>This is a paragraph</p>");`

I'm sure there are some HTML libraries out there, but this is a similar approach to PHP when you're manually echo'ing HTML code.

Comment: Hey thanks for pointing that out! Ironic indeed. :) 
I've never used that System property before - edited.

Comment: Noticed a few small mistakes, so edited again. Happy with it now. That's what happens when you don't test code out first. :p

Comment: That solves a part of my problem, but not actually the part that I was wondering about. Sorry for the ambiguity of my question.

What I actually was looking for was a way to *instantly* see the results of my program rendered as html in *eclipse*.